# Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app', and Build Failed

Tags: react-native

**This is an error I'm facing**
[image]

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "android": "^0.0.8",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "linkify-html": "^3.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.11",
    "react-native-dots-pagination": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.22.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gradient-buttons": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-marquee": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.3.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.14.10",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-viewpager": "^0.2.13",
    "react-native-wallet": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
       
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
       

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
     configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + "0.66.5"
          }
    }

    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
         maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } 
    

    }
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-html-to-pdf')
    implementation project(':react-native-share')

    implementation project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'  

    implementation project(':react-native-art')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation project(':react-native-pager-view')

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

What I have tried...

1. I think the commands which is necessary to solve the error I almost tried to solve...
2. And also I have set the environment setup very properly as the react native setup docs says ...
3. I have updated gradle version , kotlin version, react native version , npm version , node version etc...
4. I have also updated Firebase app , Firebase message and Firebase.. where Firebase app and messages version should be same...
5. I have also set up the SDK TOOLS, Android SDK in Android studio ...
6. I have uninstalled the nodes, vs code and again reinstalled it but again facing the same issue i.e. Build Failed....

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options you can try.

1. There are chances that your application is not getting enough space to get installed on emulator.
   Create new emulator in that under **Verify Configuration** click on Show Advance Settings and modify **Memory and Storage** block as shown below and now try running your application in newly created emulator.

[image]

2. Open your project into android studio and try running application from android studio and not using command line

Let me know doest it helpful to you or not.

Comment: Thanks , but I have tried this it's not worked...